# Increment copies of a certain script name that is within another script using bash

Tags: bash, loops, sed, increment

I have 100 different scripts entitled run_1.scr...run_100.scr. Within each script I have a line that says:

```
python screening_regression.py
```

I would like to create some code in bash (or from the command line) that will change the name of screening_regression.py to screening_regression1.py for run_1.scr and screening_regression2.py for run_2.scr ... and screening_regression100.py for run_100.scr. I am not sure if there is an easy command that will just allow me to loop over all of the files that are run_1.scr...run_100.scr and have me go into each file and increment the python script name that each script is calling. Any ideas?

so far I only have a piece of code that loops over the files but I am not sure how to go into each file and change the python script name in the way that I described:

```
#!/bin/bash
#for filename in /Data/run_*.scr; do
  #go into file and change screening_regression.py to screening_regression1.py
  #for the first file and then screening_regression2.py for second file etc.
#done

#num=1
for f in /home/mitche34/WIND_MOS/sub/run_screening_*.scr; do
  #sed -i -e 's/(python screening_regression_1yr.py)/(python screening_regression_1yr$num.py)/g' "$f"
  perl -i -lpe '($n)=$ARGV=~/\d+/g if $.==1\s/(python screening_regression_1yr)(.py)/$1$n$2/' "$f"
  #num=num+1
done
```

Comment: What have you got up to now?

Comment: I don't have much but I edited above with what I do have.

Comment: That's a *really* bad way to do it. Better to have a file that contains just the potentially-changing variable, modify that file only, and have the other script read it. That way you're keeping your scripts (manually-written, never changing) and your data files (potentially updated) separate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use find and perl with inplace editing like so

```
find . -name "*.scr" -exec perl -i -lpe '($n)=$ARGV=~/\d+/g if $.==1\
s/(python screening_regression)(.py)/$1$n$2/' {} \;
```

on one line

```
find . -name "*.scr" -exec perl -i -lpe '($n)=$ARGV=~/\d+/g if $.==1;s/(python screening_regression)(.py)/$1$n$2/' {} \;
```

Or using your original loop

```
#!/bin/bash
for f in /Data/run_*.scr; do

perl -i -lpe '($n)=$ARGV=~/\d+/g if $.==1\s/(python screening_regression)(.py)/$1$n$2/' "$f"

done
```

Comment: I have never used anything like this before so it looks foreign to me. Do I use this in the bash script?

Comment: Just run it from the command line or you could put it in a script if you want, gimme a sec I'll write the same using your loop instead of find.

Comment: This looks good. I copied this into my script and get an error: Backslash found where operator expected at -e line 1, near "1\"
        (Missing operator before \?)
syntax error at -e line 1, near "1\"
Execution of -e aborted due to compilation errors.

Comment: @HM14 Try it all on one line like my edit, should have worked with the escaped backslash though, so not sure whats going on.

Comment: Hmm I tried with one like and get the same errors...I edited my code above with what I have and also looked into using sed command but doesn't seem to work. The sed doesn't error it just doesn't add the number at the end of the file like I want...the pearl command gives the same error from previous comment.

Comment: @HM14 If you look at my one line command it doesn't have a backslash in it like the one in your question. I'll have to edit it anyway now though since you have numbers in your updated directory.